# Why wasn’t Ahab the subject of the lying spirit?

Tags: law, 2-chronicles, judgement, ahab, divine-counsel

> “And the Lord said, ‘Who will entice Ahab the king of Israel, that he may go up and fall at Ramoth-gilead?’ And one said one thing, and another said another.”
> ‭‭2 Chronicles‬ ‭18:19‬ ‭

God is asking who will entice Ahab

> “And he said, ‘I will go out, and will be a lying spirit in the mouth of all his prophets.’ And he said, ‘You are to entice him, and you shall succeed; go out and do so.’”
> ‭‭2 Chronicles‬ ‭18:21‬ ‭

The response was to be a lying spirit in the mouths of the prophets, why couldn’t the spirit just lie directly to Ahab and not involve the prophets?

Some things to consider

- Kings (Israeli kings under God’s leadership) were afforded certain immunities from spirits due to jurisdiction and territorial rights
- Legal requirements in heaven (please provide supporting texts)
- Ahab had to make a free will choice unimpeded by the authority of a spirit
- Ahab would not have made a decision without counsel and therefore the prophets had to be enticed

Answer (score 1):

The deceptive guidance had to come through the prophets simply because Ahab and the people in general were expecting guidance to come through that route. Solomon was given direct contact with The Lord (1 Kings ch3 vv3-14), but I'm not aware of any other king doing so. There would be no point in Ahab even pretending to have a direct word from God, because his political need was that his ally and his own people should get encouragement through "the usual channels".

So the whole point of the gathering of the prophets was to hear from them what the Lord had to say, ideally a public endorsement of what the king wanted to do. When they said "The Lord has given it into the hand of the king" (1 Kings ch22 v6) and "Thus says the Lord..." (v11), they were obviously professing to speak in the Lord's name. Jehoshaphat asks for *another* prophet of the Lord (v7), presumably because he suspects that these prophecies are fake. The prophets, being interested in pleasing their paymaster (compare Amos ch7 v12), have been listening to "lying spirits".

The short answer is that the story is about a lying spirit being sent to the prophets because the purpose of the story is to explain why there was a difference between their message and Micaiah's message (vv5-8).

Comment: A detail: It was the Lord who chose to make direct contact with Solomon after Solomon had gone through the accepted means of approach to God. He "loved the Lord, walking in  the statutes of David his father". It was not Solomon who made direct contact, for that 'means' was indirect. God took the initiative in contacting one who loved and obeyed Him. Ahab was a wicked king and God would not deal directly with him due to his gross sin and disobedience over decades. A VG answer, though!

Comment: Yes, I was using the expression "made contact" a little loosely. "Was given" would have been more accurate. In fact I think I will amend it,, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The audience of the story was the people of Judah, not the people of Israel, for the northern tribes did not know either *Kings* or *Chronicles*. Its purpose was to explain why Jehoshaphat, a righteous king whose "heart was courageous in the ways of the Lord" (17:6), made a disastrous alliance with the villainous Ahab against Syria. The story explains that he unknowingly listened to the 'wrong' prophets. These were all prophets speaking for God (18:4-7), and Jehoshaphat went with the majority. The result was that he nearly lost his life, Ahab was killed and the battle was lost. The Judahites needed to know how this beloved, righteous king could go so wrong. In terms of the OP question: *if God had sent the "lying spirit" only to Ahab, then there would be no explanation for Jehoshaphat acting as he did. Also the story provides a providential justification for Jehoshaphat joining the battle: God wanted to punish Ahab, and Ahab might not go to war without an ally.*

Consider the beginning of the next chapter:

> Jehu the son of Hana′ni the seer... said to
> King Jehosh′aphat, “Should you help the wicked and love those who hate
> the Lord? Because of this, wrath has gone out against you from the
> Lord. Nevertheless some good is found in you, for you destroyed the
> Ashe′rahs out of the land, and have set your heart to seek God.” (1 Chron 20)

This good king stood condemned by a true prophet. The story, which must have been told after the fact, let God's people know how the godly Jehoshaphat was tempted. For all he knew these were true prophets. He had no way of knowing God had put a lying spirit in their mouths. So his subjects could comfort themselves that this was all God's doing, and Jehoshaphat could retain God's blessing as king. Thus the Chronicler sums up his life:

> The Lord was with
> Jehosh′aphat, because he walked in the earlier ways of his father;
> he did not seek the Ba′als, but sought the God of his father and
> walked in his commandments, and not according to the ways of Israel.
> Therefore the Lord established the kingdom in his hand; and all Judah
> brought tribute to Jehosh′aphat; and he had great riches and honor.
> His heart was courageous in the ways of the Lord; and furthermore he
> took the high places and the Ashe′rim out of Judah. (2 Chron. 17)

Another point to consider is the providential imperative to punish Ahab, perhaps the most wicked of the evil kings in the Bible. If Ahab did not have an ally, he might not have gone to war, and his evil reign would be prolonged.

Understanding this, it is not necessary to deal the other considerations mentioned in the question. Jehoshaphat is the key here, not Ahab. The story provides a providential explanation for what would otherwise seem to be a disqualifying act by Jehoshaphat.

**The question reads: "Why wasn’t Ahab the subject of the lying spirit?" The answer is because Jehoshaphat was a necessary part of God's plan to punish Ahab, and the people of Judah needed to know why their otherwise good king Jehoshaphat allied himself with the evil king Ahab**.

Comment: Considering we are given so much backdrop, if the reason were to show Jehoshaphat’s defeat and tentative loss of life, that could have been exampled were the spirit a direct influence on Ahab regardless. Nothing changes in the story. Ahab still makes the call, it’s just that his counselors persuade him rather than the spirit itself.

Comment: You didn’t quote them did you?

Comment: sorry... I deleted the comment you are asking about. It had some errors

Comment: The way I read it, Ahab isn't the issue. His decision is already made. He's going to war and wants an ally.  It's Jehoshaphat who demands that they "inquire of the Lord"  first.

Comment: God doesn’t send the lying spirit to entice Ahab, He sends the lying spirit to entice the prophets to entice Ahab because according to you Jehoshaphat. Whether Jehoshaphat inquired or not, it was the prophets that were enticed not Ahab. It doesn’t change the event in the least and you don’t actually answer the question, do you?

Comment: I think if you read the chapter again you'll see that God's wants the lying spirit to entice Ahab not the prophets. God simply puts the spirit into the prophets' mouths. I did answer the main question but I rejected the other considerations because they become irrelevant if we accept my premise that the story's focus is Jehoshaphat/Judah not Ahab/Israel.